# Expanding/Reducing an 2D-Array in C

Tags: c, resize, realloc

How could one reallocate an 2D-Array(Array of Pointers) to expand it on each side by one(column) for example and to expand the columns also?

Thats how I malloc my array:

```
char** array = malloc((int)rows* sizeof(char*));
for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
  {
    array[row] = malloc((int)cols* sizeof(char));
    for (int column = 0; column < cols; column++) 
    {
      array[row][column] = space;
    }
```

---

Thats how I would try to reallocate it:

```
int new_rows = rows + add_rows;
int new_cols = cols + add_cols;

char**tmp = realloc( array, sizeof(char*) * (new_rows ) );
           
                  if(tmp)
                  {
                    array = tmp;
                    for(int row = 0; row < new_rows ; row++)
                    {
                      array[new_rows ] = realloc(array,sizeof((int)new_cols * sizeof(char)));
                      for (int column = 0; column < new_cols; column++) 
                      {
                        array[new_rows][column] = ' ';
                      }
                    }
                  }
        
        
        rows = new_rows;
        columns = new_columns;
        
        for (row = 0; row < rows; row++)
          {
         for (column = 0; column < columns ; column++)
            { 
               printf("%c",array[row][column]);
            }
            printf("\n");
          }
```

Comment: This code makes no sense, particularly `array[new_rows] = realloc(array, ...`. And you never saved the expanded result of the outer `realloc` either (e.g. inside `if (tmp) {` should be `array = tmp;` That won't fix everything mind you, because of the prior problem, just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: i will edit it, thank you

Comment: The `sizeof` expression inside theloop makes no sense.  HInt:  It's equivalent to `sizeof(size_t)`, i.e. it's constant.  In general, it almost never makes sense to nest `sizeof` expressions.  Remove the outer `sizeof`.

Comment: If you're going to edit it, make sure it is a proper [mcve]. if we can copy/paste what you post, and **only** what you post, and reproduce the same compile-time or run-time error that you're experiencing (which should be *clearly* conveyed in your post, along with any requisite error messages, etc.) we can nearly certainly tell you what is wrong.

Comment: And seriously, think about what `array[new_rows] = realloc(array, ...)` is actually *doing*. I wasn't kidding earlier. That `array` argument to `realloc` is absolutely wrong. In fact, *all* of the arguments in that call are wrong.

Comment: @WhozCraig but wouldnt it be the same logic to reallocated as to malloc, because the upper malloc doenst give me any mem-leaks or mem-erorrs. Pardon me if I sound dumb or arrogant in some way

Comment: `array[new_rows ] = realloc(array,` this should be `array[row] = ...` but you cannot reallocate memory that was not allocated before. The new rows have not been initialized and the stored pointers are invalid.